# Drupal CCK field does not validate using hook_nodeapi

Tags: php, validation, drupal, cck

I am trying to do a custom validation over link field in Drupal CCk.
I am currently using Link Contributed module.
So in my hook_nodeapi and case validate
Notice that this value accept unlimited values this there is a foreach.

```
case 'validate':  
  if ($node->type == 'flow')  
  {  
      foreach ($node->field_post_twitter as $twitter_v)  
      {  
        $pattern = '/(http|https|ftp):[\/]{2}twitter\.com/i';  
          if (preg_match_all($pattern, $twitter_v['url']))  
          {  
            form_set_error('not working');  
          }  
       }  
  }  
break;
```

But its not validating, while if i put it in a normal php file it DOES work.
Any ideas of what am i missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Lacking tracing in PHP, you could sprinkle around some "var_dumps()" troughout your code, to see, from high-to-low, if code is actually ran. Alternatively, install devel module and replace var_dump with `dvm()` and such helpers provided by devel module. "From high-to-low" means: check if the module is loaded at all, then if the function is called, then if your foreach runs and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use hook_form_alter to altering validate array of current form and add into this array custom validate function.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch($node->type){
    case 'test_node_form':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate';
      break;
  }
}

function my_custom_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  if(/* conditions */){
    $message = t('Oops!');
    form_set_error('', $message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the weight of your module from the `system` table in your database to the highest, so your hook is invoked last and all CCK fields -including (field_post_twitter) which is likely not yet populated in your case- are already populated.

Don't forget to clear your cache (drush cc) after all.